# Bulk Hibernate Insert Abruptly ends

Tags: hibernate

Specs:

MYSQL 5.x

Hibernate 4.9

jdk 1.8

Windows 7

Refrence URL :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Code :

```
Batch size set to 1000 : 

<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</property>

session  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
 session.save(dbvals.get(k).getObjVals());
   if (k % 1000 == 0) {
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
   }
}
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Problems:

1. Insert Objects Created : 1000
2. Insert Objects Inserted Successfully to DB :  11
3. No Exception

I am confused. Debugging did not help.

Comment: The question is unclear, What do you mean by "Insert Objects Created: 1000"? your `dbvals` are 1000 or `dbvals.get(k).getObjVals()` are 1000?

Comment: dbvals  CONTAINS 1000 OBJECTS OF AN SIMPE INSERT QUERY  ==>>>:   " Hibernate : insert into EMPLOYEE (NAME, ROLE, INSERTTIME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: When the process is executed .... only 11 of those are inserted to the Db sucessfully.  but  the other  989 times the data is NOT entered sucessfully into the DB.

Comment: dbvals.get(k).getObjVals()  would fetch each query and insert to BD...  All 1000 db data are transaction controlled.....commit or rollback ....

Comment: Try `show-sql=true` also, set Hibernate log level to `INFO` with that you can debug on what is going behind the scene, which will help you in finding the root cause. It is hard to tell what's the problem just by looking at the code you provided.

Comment: 09:44:05,785  INFO [main] SchemaUpdate:267 - HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: insert  into EMPLOYEE (NAME, ROLE, INSERTTIME, ID) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (NAME, ROLE, INSERTTIME, ID) 
values(?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: 09:44:06,213  INFO [main] StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:275 - Session Metrics {
    23330 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    23261359 nanoseconds spent preparing 11 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;

Comment: 16483872 nanoseconds spent executing 11 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    89404956 nanoseconds spent executing 11 flushes (flushing a total of 11 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}

Comment: Your logs looking good.. One more question, if you want to insert 1000 entities as a batch and  `dbvals.get(k).getObjVals()` are 1000 and you are waiting until `k is 1000` then aren't you trying to enter 1000000 as a batch ? Also could you debug and see your `for loop` for at least 11 iterations and see whats happening on 12th iteration.

Comment: I need to enter '10000' objects and i have set 1000 as the batchsize & the looper to 1000...will this create any problem....