# Hibernet Set Batchsize in code rather then in 'hibernate.cfg.xml'

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

Spec : 
MYSQL5 , Hibernate 4.3.9, jdk1.8

Process :

I have 2 SEPARATE modules inserting data into RDBMS.

1)Process A Needs to update  2500000 rows into DB
2)Process A Needs to update  5000000 rows into DB

Setup :

Setting the batch size operation is as follows in 'hibernate.cfg.xml'.

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
```

Problem :

HOW to set the 'hibernate.jdbc.batch_size' in the Code (instead of global 'hibernate.cfg.xml' configuration)

This would help me to change the 'batch_size' dynamically for each of the bulk operations.

with regards
Karthik

Comment: The difference between a batch size of 2500000 and 5000000 is going to be unnoticeable even on the 5000000 operation.  There is no need for the batch size to match the size of your operation is there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing hibernate batch size programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729255/changing-hibernate-batch-size-programatically)

Comment: What should be the size of  "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"  in comparison to the " looper  for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)"  Reason being  for a small change in loop deceleration...transaction is  incomplete.... as discussed in URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854901/bulk-hibernate-insert-abruptly-ends?noredirect=1#comment47927058_29854901